# Смена контента, поправить чтобы сразу открывался файл

Tags: ajax, файлы

Доброго времени суток пользователи проекта.
Как сделать чтобы сразу открывался контент.

```
function showContent(link) {

    var cont = document.getElementById('contentBody');  
    var loading = document.getElementById('loading');

    cont.innerHTML = loading.innerHTML;

    var http = createRequestObject();  
    if( http )   
    {  
        http.open('get', link);  
        http.onreadystatechange = function ()   
        {  
            if(http.readyState == 4)   
            {  
                cont.innerHTML = http.responseText;  
            }  
        }  
        http.send(null);      
    }  
    else   
    {  
        document.location = link;  
    }  
}

// создание ajax объекта  
function createRequestObject()   
{  
    try { return new XMLHttpRequest() }  
    catch(e)   
    {  
        try { return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP') }  
        catch(e)   
        {  
            try { return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') }  
            catch(e) { return null; }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: И как сделать плавную смену контента

Comment: Доброе время суток, пользователь. Что ты имеешь ввиду под плавной сменой контента, поясни чуток.